# Improving throughput of Kafka consumer pull when using multiple consumers

Tags: java, consumer, throughput, broker, redpanda

I am running 3 red panda's brokers with replication on 3 k8s nodes, this works perfectly fine. now I am connecting with java client and try to compare performance to learn more about configuration. broker has 12 partitions and I have there 80GB of data, each message has 4kb or 200bytes.

1 scenario:
1 group consumer can fetch around **400mb** per second, which is around **86,419 messages**, this grows to around **823,043 messages** when payload is smaller (200bytes). consumer fetches all 12 partitions in multiple pulls.

2 scenario:
4 consumers run on 4 different threads, each consumer assigns its own, single, unique partition (yes I fetch only 4 partition in this scenario). I expected that I should get at least same throughput for each consumer and in overall improved performance - what I observe is that each consumer can fetch around 100-200MB per second, which sums back to 400-600MB

3 scenario:
single pod that starts multiple group consumers. Multiple pods, each starts single group consumer. Again I don't get improved throughput.

consumer pods are run on different node group than red panda. I have 16cpus and 32 Gbps Network Bandwidth on each node, that should be enough to push data between nodes.

my consumer configuration is

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, 100);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, 4 * 1024 * 1_00_000);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 4 * 1024 * 1_00_000);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1_000_000);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10_000);
```

I haven't seen tcp configuration on consumer side, to experiment, **I am still looking what should I set on red panda's side to improve throughput**.

each RedPanda s broker is run on k8s in GCP `c2-standard-16` which is described as

```
vCPU    16
Memory  64 GB
CPU Manufacturer    Intel
CPU Platform    Intel Cascade Lake
CPU Base Frequency  3.1 GHz
CPU Turbo Frequency 3.8 GHz
CPU Max. Turbo Frequency    3.9 GHz
Network Bandwidth   32 Gbps
```